# How to convert text node into object node to add a child node

Tags: json, nodes, marklogic

I am using Javascript and JSON files. I am trying to create a child node and insert a value into that node

The base setup is:

```
    declareUpdate();
xdmp.documentInsert("/example.json",
{"a":"aa","b":"bb"});
```

What I would like to see is a child node in either a or b with some data.

```
declareUpdate(); var doc = cts.doc("/example.json"); var docObj = doc.toObject(); docObj. = "this is a much different value"; xdmp.nodeInsertChild(cts.doc("/example.json").xpath("/a"), docObj);

[javascript] XDMP-CHILDNODEKIND: xdmp.nodeInsertChild(Sequence(xdmp.unpath("fn:doc('/foo.json')/text('foo')")), Text("this is a child node value")) -- text nodes cannot have text node children
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error suggests your attempt of adding a JSON property as immediate child of the document node. MarkLogic object node can’t have document node children.

One effective way of updating JSON document node is to update/replace the JavaScript object node with your construct. (Note: You can’t insert a text expression directly into MarkLogic JSON node, insert a named node instead.)

If the desired result is something like

```
{
  "a": {
    "a1": "aa", 
    "a2": "new child node"
  },
  "b": "bb"
}
```

, then simply apply a node replace:

```
declareUpdate();
const doc = cts.doc("/example.json"); 
const newNode = { "a1":"aa", "a2":"new child node" };
xdmp.nodeReplace(doc.xpath("/a"), newNode);
```